# UIImage data coming back as null

Tags: ios, uiimage, base64

I am trying to convert a UIImage to NSData then NSData to Base64 string.

Here is my method for processing the image:

```
- (void)processImage:(UIImage*)image{
    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
    [self.spinnerOutlet setAlpha:0.0f];
    [self.spinnerOutlet startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        NSData *myData = nil;
        myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

        float sysVer = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
        if (sysVer >= 7.00) {
            // Convert image
            myData = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
        }

        NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[myData bytes]];
        snapShotInBase64 = myString;

        NSLog(@"Snapshot in base64 string: %@", myString);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // BACK TO THE UI THREAD
            [self showSuccessAlertView:@"Great" message:@"Sending Image..."];

            isProcessingImage = NO;
            [self sendImagePostRequest];
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that the NSLog comes back null!

```
NSLog(@"Snapshot in base64 string: %@", myString);
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? What exists? What version of iOS are you running on?

Comment: Why do you think that a NSData that holds an image can be converted into a UTF8Encoded string?  That NSData could have a null character anywhere in the data, thereby ending the string and releasing the rest of the memory.  That is a very bad technique.  I'm not sure why you need a 64bit string from your image, but you can check this link out for 64bit NSData coding: https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64

Comment: found a solution similar to this. see below :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Base64 NSData extension class.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64

you can literally just use his Base64.h and .m files and then you can call one method to convert your data to base64. It is magical.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one. I think it's help to you.

Image to base64:-

```
if let updatedImage = originalImaglable.updateImageOrientionUpSide() {

        let imageData: NSData? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(updatedImage, 0.1) as NSData?

        let dataImage = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

        if let strdata = dataImage {

            str_photo = strdata
        }
  }
```